# AWS Deployment with Rails - configuration file in .ebextensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

I have a configuration file in .ebextensions/packages.config.

```
packages: 
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

When I deploy on AWS ElacticBeanstalk, I have this error :

> [Instance: i-195762fc Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Yum does not have postgresql-devel available for installation.

If you have an idea of the error I have made, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: I have been getting the same error as of yesterday as well.  Hope someone out there has an answer.

Comment: have you solved this already? I'm having this problem

Comment: You'd think this could be something they'd put in the "Adding a Database" section...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remplace postgresql-devel by postgresql92-devel or postgresql93-devel

Comment: Is postgresql92 or postgresql93 a client version? Why isn't it in sync with postgresql95 for postgresql 9.5.2...?